# Editing database from front-end, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm able to update the database fine, but how do I get the current information extracted from the database into the Edit textboxes.

This is my current code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Details">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <asp:Label ID="passwordname" runat="server" 
                Text="Current Password:" />
        <asp:Label ID="password" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:TextBox ID="editpassword" runat="server" 
    placeholder='<%# Eval("Password") %>' Text="New Password">
</asp:TextBox>
```

How do I get the textbox editpassword to show the current password stored?

Comment: Is this the password for a user's account to log into your site?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try binding the Value of the asp:TextBox?

Also, instead of using Eval(), consider model binding.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="Details" ItemType="MyNamespace.MyClass">

<asp:TextBox ID="editpassword" runat="server" 
    Value='<%# BindItem.Password %>' Text="New Password">
</asp:TextBox>
```

[Setting up databind for a listview using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347446/setting-up-databind-for-a-listview-using-c-sharp)